# How do I receive an output from VS community in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

I was doing a basic "Hello World" program with the code from w3school, but why is the output like this? Why isn't there just a printed 'Hello World' instead it's something difficult to understand.

Can I have an explanation?

Comment: Click the dark green arrow next to ConsoleApp1. It will open another Console Window.

Comment: @PeterChikov: OP did that already, as evidenced by *"The program '[22608] ConsoleApp1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."*

Answer (score 2):

When you run your app, it should open a console window, separate from Visual Studio. Your program output will appear in there.

The complicated stuff you can see is the debugging info VS outputs. You probably don't need to worry about it right now.

Answer (score 0):

The picture shows that the complex content is debug information and output. Eventually your code will run as a result of the Visual Studio console window.